# How, using sinon, to test if a method will eventually be invoked

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, sinon

I'm trying to use sinon to verify that certain steps in a procedure are executed, I don't know when exactly are the steps executed, I just want to confirm that the method I'm testing will invoke the given function.

Here is what I currently do:

```
describe('Native calls handling', function() {

    var ctrl;

    beforeEach(function() {
        ctrl = new EthernetController($placeholder, notifications, null, nav);
    });

    // What I currently do
    it('Should perform internet check on `Connected` event', function(done) {
        var errorTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            internetCheck.restore();
            done(new Error('Assertion failed, internetCheck was not executed'));
        }, 1500);

        var internetCheck = sinon.stub(ctrl, 'internetCheck', function() {
            clearTimeout(errorTimeout);

            internetCheck.restore();
            done();

            return Promise.resolve(true);
        });

        app.notify('system:ethernet:connected');
    });

    // Functionality I'm looking for
    it('Should perform internet check on `Connected` event', function(done) {
        var internetCheck = sinon.stub(ctrl, 'internetCheck', function() {
            return Promise.resolve(true);
        });

        // Fail the test if the function is not called within $ ms
        // Also restore the stub
        internetCheck.cancelationTime = 1500;

        // Trigger the assertion after/if the function is called
        internetCheck.whenCalled(function(params...) {// assertion })
            .timedOut(done);


        app.notify('system:ethernet:connected');
    });
});
```

The `Connected` event will trigger an async procedure that in the end will perform `internetCheck`
Is there something similar to what I'm looking for

Edit: 
The real problem for me was that the method used promises internally but returns **void** so I have no easy way of finding out when the procedure is finished.
I'll post an answer as to what I ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled on [this solution](https://github.com/bahmutov/q-flush/blob/master/index.js) that is for **node.js**. And since our project used Q promises but there is no `process` object in the borwser I rolled my own.

It doesn't involve **sinon** but it solves my problem:

```
/**
 * Make testing of Q promises as synchronous code
 * Calling process.apply() will complete all pending Q promises
 */
(function(global) {
    'use strict';

    var _queue = [];

    // Fake process object
    global.process = {
        // process.toString() is used internally by Q (v1.4.1) to recognize environment
        // We are lying to it to exploit it's inner workings
        toString: function() {
            return '[object process]';
        },

        nextTick: function(cb) {
            _queue.push(cb);
        },

        apply: function() {
            console.info('Flushing pending tasks');

            var head;
            while (head = _queue.shift()) {
                head();
            }
        }
    };

})(window);
```

And then the test case:

```
describe('Native calls handling', function() {

    var ctrl;

    beforeEach(function() {
        ctrl = new EthernetController($placeholder, notifications, null, nav);
    });

    it('Should perform internet check on `Connected` event', function() {
        var internetCheck = sinon.stub(ctrl, 'internetCheck');
        internetCheck.returns(Q.resolve(true));

        app.notify('system:ethernet:connected');
        process.apply();

        expect(internetCheck).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```